# SwiftUI Parallax Motion Effect causes Lag when switching views or opening sheets

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found [this code](https://trailingclosure.com/device-motion-effect/), and adapted it to my own app. It seems to work fine for my use. The issue I am experiencing and not sure how to resolve is that when I switch views or open a sheets over the `PostView`. It seems like the motion updates continue even when they're not needed, causing the app to lag and become very sluggish and choppy as it seems to render the effect nonstop.

Code for motion effect:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion

class MotionManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pitch: Double = 0.0
    @Published var roll: Double = 0.0

    private var manager: CMMotionManager

    init() {
        self.manager = CMMotionManager()
        self.manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/90
        self.manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) { [weak self] (motionData, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            if let motionData = motionData {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let newPitch = motionData.attitude.pitch
                    let newRoll = motionData.attitude.roll
                    // Use nil-coalescing operator to provide a default value (e.g., 0.0) if nil
                    if abs(newPitch - (self?.pitch ?? 0.0)) > 0.01 || abs(newRoll - (self?.roll ?? 0.0)) > 0.01 {
                        self?.pitch = newPitch
                        self?.roll = newRoll
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ParallaxMotionModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var manager: MotionManager
    var magnitude: Double

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .offset(x: CGFloat(manager.roll * magnitude), y: CGFloat(manager.pitch * magnitude))
    }
}
```

Here is my `PostView` code snippet that renders random image dynamically inside a frame:

```
struct PostView: View {
    enum LayoutType {
        case singleImage, listView
    }

    var post: SomeTest
    var layoutType: LayoutType

    @StateObject private var motionManager = MotionManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        switch layoutType {
        case .singleImage:
            VStack {
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    // Apply ParallaxMotionModifier to displayImageView
                    displayImageView(for: post)
                        .modifier(ParallaxMotionModifier(manager: motionManager, magnitude: 15))
                        .drawingGroup()
                        .frame(width: 370, height: 570)
                        .scaleEffect(1.1)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .clipped() 
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 550)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 6, x: 0, y: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The issue happens when I switch from `singleImage` (where the parallax effect is active) to `listView`, or when I open a sheet for example over the `singleImage` view. The scrolling in the list view becomes extremely laggy, and I suspect the motion effect from the single image view is still active and updating in the background.